# Problems importing DLL with BYTE* output

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I'm importing a function from an unmanaged DLL into C#. The C++ function signature is as follows

```
int RF_PowerOnEx(int nDev, int nCardType, DWORD* pdwRXSize, BYTE* lpbRXData)
```

I am importing it as follows

```
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int RF_PowerOnEx(int nDev, int nCardType, out int pdwRXSize, out byte[] lpbRXData);
```

However doing so gives me a System.AccessViolationException. I have successfully imported the other functions except this particular one. Both pdwRXSize and lpbRXData are treated as output. The integer and buffer is initialized, then passed into the function which then fills up the buffer.  Help!!!! I seem to be able to pass input parameters into the DLL but can't get output parameters. I've tried passing a Stringbuilder object to no avail.   Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Edit: Typo

Comment: Have you tried using `ref int` or `System.IntPtr` for `pdwRXSize`?

Comment: What is the semantics of pdwRXSize and lpbRXData arguments?

Comment: pdwRXSize and lpbRXData are passed by reference. The function writes to these two values. pdwRXSize will give the number of bytes written into lpbRXData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you declare the managed signature like this

```
public static extern int RF_PowerOnEx(int nDev, int nCardType, out int pdwRXSize, [out] IntPtr lpbRXData);
```

and then marshall the byte array "by hand" directly from unmanaged memory, using the length information which should be set in `pdwRXSize`.

You really need to know more about the function implementation: in particular, is the caller supposed to do something to release the memory containing the data buffer?

Comment: Can you explain more about marshalling "by hand"? Or at the least point me towards the right direction to research it? Thanks!

Comment: @user1456204 Is it possible that this is a windows-style api where the caller must preallocate and pass the buffer ptr and specify the size?  I agree with ChrisDickson that you should check the docos because special care must be done if the API is passing you a ptr to memory that it allocated.  This is why most Win APIs don't do that.

Comment: What Chris means is, if the API is allocating a buffer and just returning you a Ptr to it, you need to us that Ptr and copy the data into your own byte buffer.  But that is only if the API is really working that way.

Comment: Marshal.Copy [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx] is your friend.

Comment: @tcarvin: you are right to sound a note of caution, but given the unmanaged signature and the argument names, I'm not sure I can imagine how else the API could be working.

Comment: No idea about the implementation. The documentation i'm working with is also quite sparse. I think the practice is  you allocate the byte buffer, pass it into the function, and then the function writes into that buffer.

Comment: I've seen APIs like this where you call it with a null buffer ptr first and it passes back the count it wants and then you call it a second time with the allocated buffer.  You never really know with these small hardware shops.

Comment: @user1456204, well if you are sure you are passing it an allocated buffer, make sure that you do actually pre-allocate it and just pass it as an array with no markup.  The default marshalling behavior should be fine.

Comment: @user1456204 Make sure you share what worked for you in the end so others can learn too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `out byte[]`, that's equivalent to BYTE**.  Make it just plain byte[].  And pdwRXSize is `ref`, set it to the size of the array.  Call it like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[666];
int size = buffer.Length;
int retval = RF_PowerOnEx(device, cardtype, ref size, buffer);
if (retval == okay) processData(buffer, size);
```

You'll have to make an educated guess at the required array size.

Answer (score 0):

`EntryPointNotFoundException` is thrown because the name of your .NET declaration doesn't fit with the unmanaged declaration (because of the underscore).

Try:

```
    [DllImport("TP9000.dll", EntryPoint = "RF_PowerOnEx")]
    public static extern int RFPowerOnEx(int nDev, int nCardType, out int pdwRXSize, out byte[] lpbRXData);
```